# If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then $f'(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then $f'(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

If this proposition is not true, show me one counterexample. thanks.

Comment: Do you mean Riemann integrable or Lebesgue integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x^2\,\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. The derivative exists (even at $0$), but is not Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$, because unbounded, and not Lebesgue-integrable, because not absolutely integrable. The improper integral is finite, though.

Comment: I don't get it: how can a *continuous* function in a compact set (in this case, $\;[0,1]\;$)  be *unbounded*? This contradicts directly Weierstrass' Theorem.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, $f'$ isn't.

Comment: @DonAntonio, it's $f'$ that's unbounded, not $f$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You're completely right: I didn't even see the ' sign for the derivative and thought all the time that it was about $\;f\;$ . Thanks.